# Running shell commands from PHP - With root permissions or sudo

Tags: php, linux, root, sudo

I'll explain what I'm trying to do, because someone might have a much better and completely different approach to this.

I'm trying to install FFMPEG, but not just install it, I'm making an automated installer that installs some PHP scripts and also FFMPEG if it's not already installed.

I can't find any automated PHP scripts that can install FFMPEG, so I'm guessing this is more difficuilt than I thought.

I had 3 options to do this:

- Build from source on the server using the exec function, this
  requires root permissions.
- Find a pre-compiled binary of FFMPEG, easily done, and I did it, but
  then I realised it didn't have the correct codecs so wasn't working.
- Use YUM or APT-GET to install FFMPEG, this would be great but it
  requires root permissions.

So, how can I either:

Use YUM/APT-GET from PHP and set sudo

OR

Install codecs for FFMPEG after it has been compiled. Using the pre-compiled binaries that I found, if it were possible then I could just install the missing codecs (lame mp3 I think. Maybe others too). Or do the codecs need to be built into the binary.

I think the prefered option is to use YUM/APT-GET as my targets are mostly Centos 5 and maybe Ubuntu aswell.

Comment: +1 for explaining what you intend to do and be open to other approaches. Also, can't you compile it inside your home directory with `./configure --prefix=~/ffmpeg && make && make install` and copy needed codecs there too if you need them?

Comment: @Carlos Campderrós: Thanks, I will have a look into it, although not 100% sure what I'm doing on linux really. I'm just picking it up as I go.

Comment: You need to explain more what you're trying to achieve. Is it a general purpose thing? Or is it going to be used in a controlled environment, e.g. your own computers? Because what you're trying to do in pretty unusual and many people would not be happy with this idea if you forced it on them. FFMPEG carries a long tail of complex dependencies, installing it automatically on a random computer is a bad idea in my opinion.

Comment: @haimg: Yeah it's general purpose, I have some PHP video converting srcipts (turn-key thing), and to make it even more turn-key I'm making an installer that installs/configures the php scripts and then also installs FFMPEG if it's not already there.

Comment: ffmpeg is not available in Centos 5 using standard repositories only. I suggest you reconsider your idea. Installing php scripts is one thing. Installing ffmpeg, with its large dependencies and licensing issues, fromm third-party repositories, automatically, is quite a different one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[sudo in php](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/sudo.htm) is a lot easier if you use SSH.  Among other things you can make use of "expect" to wait for the appropriate prompts.  If there's a way to do that with the built in exec() or system() I'm not aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you end up compiling from source or installing from a repo you can handle the install processs through this project that allows PHP to obtain and interact with a real Bash shell. Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
$shell    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('bash', true);
$return1  = $shell->exeCmd('yum -y install FFMPEG');
//the return will be a string containing the return of the command
echo $return1;
```

You will need to deal with the edge cases when i.e. there is a GPG key that need to be accepted or dependencies are conflicting. But the project lets you script all Bash interaction.